# How can i count the number of columns in a csv file using C?

Tags: c, csv

I have a project in c where the program should show the number of lines and columns in a cvs file.
I have already done the lines but i can't make it count the columns.
I had an ideia in witch i could count the number of "," and add 1. It works but not in every csv file the columns are separeted by commas, so it doesn't work for every csv file.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COMMA 44


file_info(){

    FILE *f;
    int countlines = 0;
    int countcols = 0;

    char c;

    f = fopen("moradas.csv", "r");

    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file!");
        return 0;
    }

    for (c = getc(f); c != EOF; c = getc(f)){
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
    countlines++;
    if ((c == COMMA) && (countlines == 0))
    countcols++;

    }


    fclose(f);
    printf("Lines: %d \n", countlines);
    printf("Cols: %d \n", countcols + 1);

    return 0;

}


main(){

    int option;

    printf("Chose option\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);

switch(option)
{
    case 1:
    file_info();
    break;

    case 2:
    printf("2\n");
    break;
    default:
    printf("Chose valid option!\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input?

Comment: @SuperStormer you mean my csv file?

Comment: Yes, we need to be able to reproduce what happens.

Comment: here they are: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Ilxv87Vl86R2D9mgkFE_CfxE5FN53Ln/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it works for "moradas.csv" because the columns are separeted by commas, but in "proxim.csv" it doesn't works, obviously because it has no commas

Comment: `Can't open file!` is the canonical example of a useless error message. Use `f = fopen("moradas.csv", "r"); if (f == NULL){perror("moradas.csv"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes i will do that in the end of the project because it is not my priority right now

Comment: "but not in every csv file the columns are separeted by commas" then by definition, thats not a csv file

Comment: @SuperStormer yeah i thought that too, but i was given 2 files, "moradas.csv" and "proxim.csv", and in "proxim" it has no commas and now i don't know what to do :/

Comment: If it has no commas, the the column count is 1.  Or, you might want to give the user the ability to specify the divider with a parameter.  eg. `column-count -d '|'` would use `|` as a column separator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way. You have to know the type seperation before counting the columns. Maybe you could give the character as a parameter to the function so the program knows what to count.

Comment: like declaring a separation character, in wich it would separate every column?

Comment: Yes. Instead of asking (c == COMMA) just (c==seperator) or somethink like that